# VS 2019 displaying push error without specifying any error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting this message from VS2019 in the 'Git Changes' window when I push code in my repository:

*Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.*

But there's no message in the Output window and furthermore, I checked the repository and the new code is there. This has been happening consistently since last week. What's happening and how do I make the message go away?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, but I can't really tell without seeing your Git Integration configuration and the steps you are using to reproduce the error.

I would suggest filing a bug report under the "Send Feedback" button (just under the `X` close button). Make sure to supply a detailed description and screenshots.

I personally stopped using the built-in Git/Github integration as it is pretty new and still has some problems.

In the meantime, [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) is a good alternative.